# Form to appear in a popup panel

Tags: css, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following file setup:

In `forms.py`

```
class TableCheckInForm(forms.Form):
    guest_count = forms.IntegerField(min_value =0)
```

In `views.py`:

```
def table_checkin_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TableCheckInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            cd = form.cleaned_data
    else:
        form = TableCheckInForm()
    return render(request,
                  'table/table_checkin.html', {'form': form})
```

In the template `table_view.html`

```
<script src="{% static 'js/table.js' %}"></script>
...
<button class="button checkin_button" onclick="openForm()">Check In</button>
...
```

In another template `table_checkin.html`

```
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'js/table.js' %}"></script>

  <div id="table_checkin_form">
    <h1>Check-In</h1>
    <form class="form-container" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="submit" class="table_checkin" onclick="closeForm()">Check In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

In static Javascript file `table.js`

```
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("table_checkin_form").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("table_checkin_form").style.display = "none";
}
```

In `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', views.table_view, name='table_view'),
    path('1/checkin/', views.table_checkin_view, name='table_checkin_view'),
    ...
]
```

I am trying to implement a popup panel that contains the form above, similar to this example from W3Schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup_form).

Suppose I am currently on the template `table_view.html`. When I click the button `checkin_button`, I would like to have the form popup in a small panel that renders `table_checkin.html`. That means, in the background, I would like still see the template `table_view.html`.
But the form in my case always appear in a completely new page (since it has its own url).
Putting aside the css effect, is it possible to have one view containing a form being rendered as a popup on top of another view?

If you have other suggestions to implement this effect, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open a separate URL to render the form.

To create the example you're referencing, the form is included as a div in what would be your table_view.html page. It's hidden by default, then the div is displayed when on clicks the Open Form button.

Sticking the code from the first button in the W3Schools example to the end of the script (before the closing body tag) into table_view.html should make their example run for you. Then replace the form and action info. Add CSS as needed.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't using the form naked like that have the risk of cross-site attack? I am putting the form in its own template so that i could use stuff like ```{% csrf_token %}``` or ```crispy-form``` later. Or is there a way to avoid this risk in the W3Schools example?

Comment: You'll need to insert the csrf_token to use Post method on the form. Using Javascript to temporarily hide and then reveal the contents of a page is perfectly acceptable.